# Auto collection view cell Height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, cell, sift

I have a custom cell with a label. I get the text from the server, and the cell in the collection must choose the height so that all the text fits and is visible. Now I use this method, but I do not know how to change the height so that it adjusts.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
       
        return   CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: 90)
      
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:- Create a function to estimate the size of your text: This method will return a height value that will fit your string!**

```
private func estimateFrameForText(text: String) -> CGRect {
    //we make the height arbitrarily large so we don't undershoot height in calculation
    let height: CGFloat = 999

    let size = CGSize(width: yourDesiredWidth, height: height)
    let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading.union(.UsesLineFragmentOrigin)
    let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(18, weight: UIFontWeightLight)]

    return NSString(string: text).boundingRectWithSize(size, options: options, attributes: attributes, context: nil)
}
```

**Step 2: Use or override delegate method below:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var height: CGFloat = 0

   //we are just measuring height so we add padding constant to give the label some room to breathe! 
    var padding: CGFloat = 10

let stringFromViewModel = “Hello please pass your string here from array…”
    //estimate each cell's height
         height = estimateFrameForText(stringFromViewModel).height + padding
    return CGSize(width: yourDesiredWidth, height: height)
}
```

Comment: Where should I write the first method?

Comment: You can write in the controller where you are using the CollectionView. Or you can create an extension if you will be using a method on multiple controllers or for the future use.

Comment: Sorry but no. Many errors about unknown variable  & operators "<".
I have a cell and there is a label for the text. The text I get from the server through viewModel. And depending on the size of the text, you need to set the height of the cell.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please update the string value for the variable "stringFromViewModel".